# PYTHON: Given the variables x, y, and z, each associated with an int, write a fragment of code that assigns the smallest of these to variable min

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

This is what I have so far: (It doesn't seem to work)

```
if (x < y) and (x < z):
   min = x
elif (y < x) and (y < z):
   min = y
elif (z < y) and (z < x):
   min = z
```

Comment: That code should work just fine. If you don’t overwrite `min`, you can also use the built-in function `min(x, y, z)` to get the minimum value. Also make sure that you check for number equality. All your `<` should be `<=` signs so that for `x == y == z`, you still get a result.

Comment: Entering "Given the variables x, y, and z, each associated with an int, write a fragment of code that assigns the smallest of these to variable min" into your favorite search engine yields quite a few verbatim results. You should also disclose that this is a homework assignment so we can help you learn instead of just giving you the answer.

Comment: min = min([x, y, z])

Answer (score 1):

Just use `min = min(x, y, z)` this should give you the smallest value in min.

Answer (score 0):

give this shorter version a try:

```
min = min(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if x<=y and x<=z:
    min=x
if y<=x and y<=z:
    min=y
if z<=x and z<=y:
    min=z
```

Answer (score 0):

```
min=x
if y<min:
  min=y
if z<min:
  min=z
```

It is the answer accepted by Pearson's online tutorial, which is where the original poster got the question.  The question calls for you to find the min of the three numbers, not which number is the min.  If all three are equal they will all be equal to the min.

The purpose of the exercise from the book is to understand conditional statements.  Using a function call defeats the purpose of the excercise